# Is there a way to specify a standalone category for your feed?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'd like to narrow down my feed to core Python and core C.  Currently, if I favorite "python" and "c," I get feed matches for questions that may contain "python" and "c" in their tags.  I don't want that.  I want questions that are *solely* tagged either "python" *or* "c."  Not, for example, a post tagged *"'python' 'django' 'numpy' "* or *"'c' 'ncurses' 'sockets'."*

Rather than go through all tags, ignoring each one that isn't "python" nor "c," is there a way to tell Stack Overflow, "Only show me questions wherein 'python' or 'c' are the sole tags."

If this isn't possible, is something in the works for that?  It'd be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not exactly what you want, but you can already do *or* queries with tags.

For example, try searching [`[python] or [c]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+or+c).

You can then put all the tags you would like to ignore in your *ignored tags* list to have anything tagged `[numpy]` or `[ncurses]` grayed out.

Comment: Yeah, this definitely isn't what I'm looking for, sorry. I was posts that are exclusively one tag, not one tag within a list of tags.  And I don't want to go through a list of other tags to ignore them.  That's an excessive task.